# Error-Select inside count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this procedure

```
SELECT COUNT( a.id_badania ) AS iloscBadan, COUNT( b.zdjecie ) AS iloscZdjec, COUNT (SELECT id_badania FROM Badania WHERE status='W trakcie realizacji';)
FROM Badania a
INNER JOIN Zdjecia b ON a.id_badania = b.id_badania
```

And this error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT id_badania FROM Badania WHERE status='W trakcie realizacji') FROM Badani' at line 1

I don't know sql well.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: remove the Semicolon after 'W trakcie realizacji'

Answer (score 1):

You can use sum with case statement for to count the values for a particular status

```
    SELECT COUNT( a.id_badania )   AS iloscBadan, COUNT( b.zdjecie ) AS iloscZdjec, Sum( case when status='W trakcie realizacji' then 1 else 0 end ) 
     FROM Badania a
     INNER JOIN Zdjecia b ON a.id_badania = b.id_badania
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put a subquery in an aggregation function.  And you have a semicolon in the middle of the query.  I am guessing that you just want condtiional aggregation.  Either this:

```
SELECT COUNT( a.id_badania ) AS iloscBadan, COUNT( b.zdjecie ) AS iloscZdjec,
       SUM(status = 'W trakcie realizacji')
FROM Badania a INNER JOIN
     Zdjecia b
     ON a.id_badania = b.id_badania;
```

Or:

```
SELECT COUNT( a.id_badania ) AS iloscBadan, COUNT( b.zdjecie ) AS iloscZdjec,
       COUNT(DISTINCT case when status = 'W trakcie realizacji' then a.id_badania end)
FROM Badania a INNER JOIN
     Zdjecia b
     ON a.id_badania = b.id_badania;
```